# How can I make coffee syrup with caramel taste?

Tags: sugar, coffee, caramelization

I have seen several recipes for coffee syrup, but none of them with a simple caramel taste. Is getting the caramel taste as easy as using brown sugar instead of white sugar, or do I need to find some store selling caramel flavour (essence)?

Comment: Christian, could you please provide a reference for the recipes that you have seen / tried? What do you want to use the syrup for? Is this a syrup to sweeten your coffee or a coffee and caramel syrup for desserts?

Comment: Sorry, it's for coffee flavoring/sweetening. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually just make caramel. Place about 1 1/4 cup sugar and 1/4 cup in a heavy bottom pan and dissolve over low-medium heat then crank up the heat and let cook, without stirring, until the mixture turns a golden amber colour and starts smoking. Then use the resulting caramel to sweeten your coffee :-)

Comment: 1/4 cup water... I assume?

Comment: So, I actually tried this, and it worked so-so. It didn't get quite as much caramel flavor as the store-bought stuff, and I probably cooked it too long, I had to spoon it out and into my coffee ;)